# Magento 2 Email Showing template hints

Tags: email, debugging, magento2

I'm in production mode and a custom module is sending the template hints. Here is an example of a template hint above a block:

```
/var/www/html/website.com/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml
```

Here is the line of code to send the email:

```
$this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
```

Other modules use essentially the same code to send notifications and don't have this problem.

Comment: Did you ever get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I used `$state->setAreaCode('frontend');`, but email template has debug hints. After this I used `$state->setAreaCode('global');` and email tamplate hasn't debug hints.

```
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');
$this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
```

I try this on Magento 220

Comment: Please add some description to this code explaining what is going on and why. This is good practice. If you don't, your answer is in risk of being deleted. It has already been flagged as low quality.